# get JSON instance to jsp through calling AJAX

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json

I get the **JSONOject** from my bean in my helper class.

*Inside helper*

```
public JSONObject init() throws Exception{
        // initializations codes are here
        JSONObject json = JSONObject.fromObject(bean);
        return json;
}
```

Then I need to access above JSONObject inside a jsp calling through ajax request when loading the jsp(to assign javascript variable like bellow)

*inside jsp*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var VAR_JSON = // need to get the JSON through AJAX
});
```

previously I had a code like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var VAR_JSON = <%=helper.init()%>                               
</script>
```

how can I achive this by AJAX ?

thanks in advance..!!

Comment: Try $.ajax with `json` options and in `url:"<%=helper.init()%>"` http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, stop thinking JSP. The JSP is (part of) what executes on your server when a request is being handled. That in turn returns a response to the browser (usually a webpage); your JavaScript (and therefore your AJAX request) run in the user's browser on that webpage, not in your JSP.

jQuery provides a function specifically designed for getting JSON through an AJAX request; it's called [`jQuery.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/). You'd use it something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var VAR_JSON;
        function yourFunction() {
            // do something with VAR_JSON here
        }

        $.getJSON('yoururl.do', function(response) {
            VAR_JSON = response;
            yourFunction();
        });
    });
</script>
```

It's important to note that you can't do `var VAR_JSON = $.getJSON()` because the function is asynchronous, and therefore doesn't return the JSON (it returns something else - see the documentation linked above). You instead need to provide a callback function that will execute when the asynchronous request returns a successful response, which will then set your variable and call another function that uses it.

Also note that you won't need to call something like `JSON.parse()` because jQuery does that for you; you've told it you're expecting JSON back so it parses that string to get the resulting object or array, which is then in turn passed as an argument to the callback function.

Comment: in struts 1 how can I forward json object instead of jsp. I'm new to java so kindly help me please

Comment: @user1727557 I personally use the [json-taglib](http://json-taglib.sourceforge.net/) which is a set of JSP tags for generating JSON. You'd need to add a new forward for your action in Struts that directs to a JSP to generate the JSON instead of the standard JSP for your webpage.